# ReduceLROnPlateau gives error with ADAM optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Is it because adam optimizer changes the learning rate by itself. 
I get an error saying 'Attempting to use uninitialized value Adam_1/lr'
I guess there is no point in using ReduceLRonPlateau as Adam will automatically change learning rate.Anyways i have updated the codee
Update:
Code:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')

 callback_reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                                     factor=0.1, 
                                     min_lr=1e-4,
                                     patience=0,
                                     verbose=1
                                    )
model.fit(xTrain,yTrain,epochs=100,batch_size=10,validation_data=(xTest,yTest),verbose=2,callbacks=[callback_reduce_lr])
```

Error://Attempting to use uninitialized value Adam_1/lr

I read somewhere that initializing  adam doesnt work while working with ReduceLROnPlateau,,i have tried to initialize the weights too but i got the same error

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have updated the code,Adam will do the adaptive learning by itself right,,so is it because of that the ReduceLRonPlateau doesnt work here

Comment: With what parameters to you initialize the Adam optimizer. Could you please add this part to your code?

Comment: @Djib2011 I read somewhere that initializing  adam doesnt work while working with ReduceLROnPlateau,,i have tried to initialize the weights too but i got the same error

Comment: I've used `ReduceLROnPlateau` with adam in keras without the error you mention. It also appeared to work, as the model begins stabilizing once the loss plateaus. One difference is that I monitor the regular loss instead of the validation one, however I don't think that is the nature of your error.

Comment: @Djib2011 Thanks fore the comment.I dont know why i am getting it,,saw some queries with same problem online without eg :https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/issues/170

Comment: @kerastf maybe some of the parameters of `ReduceLROnPlateau` are conflicting with Adam's? When I did it I used the default parameters on `ReduceLROnPlateau`. Could you try that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the question's comments, keras' [ReduceLROnPleteau](https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau), **does** appear to work for its default parameters:

```
# keras' ReduceLROnPlateau callback default parameters:
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=10,
                              verbose=0, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001,
                              cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
```

I tried to recreate the error to try and identify which parameter causes it, but I couldn't. Due to this, I believe that the error doesn't appear for all input shapes or models.

However, I can say for sure that, with the correct parameters, `ReduceLROnPlateau` **does work** with Adam.

Comment: @kerastf how did you know that it worked? It is just because the error went away or  did you try printing out the learning rate and saw that the learning rate was decreasing by the factor of 0.1 when no improvement in the val_loss was seen for 10 epochs?

Comment: from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau was missing.